# Is it possible that the method call output is printed after the execution of the statement next to the call?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the below code what could be the predicted output?

```
public class Threads2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("run.");
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Threads2());
        t.start();
        System.out.println("End of method.");
    }
}
```

The possible outcome given as the answers are:

```
End of method.
run.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem
```

OR

```
run.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem 
End of method.
```

According to me only answer 2nd is possible, please help me to understand.

Comment: Why should both outcomes not be possible, you think?

Comment: Technically all combinations are possible. You're creating a classical 'race condition'. 'run' is executed concurrently to the main method, which is why any order is possible. HOWEVER: Since main ends, the thread also gets terminated along with it, which is why 'Run' and 'Problem' may not get printed at all.

Comment: @Ataylor It's not a daemon thread, so in the absence of `System.exit` the program will exit some time after both threads have finished.

Comment: (Mixing `System.out` and `System.err` can also cause problems.)

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup,  Thanks for replying and giving the suggestions

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline  Thanks for replying and giving the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution will result in two threads, the main thread (the one running the main-method), and the thread created in the main method. Since you can't guarantee anything when it comes to the order that the threads will run, there are multiple orders that the code could run.

So lets call the main thread Thread1, and the created thread Thread2. The possibilties then are, after Thread2 has been started:

1. Thread1 gets the processor time first. ("End of method..." get printed first)
2. Thread2 gets the processor time first. ("run" get printed first)

and, there is actually a third possibility (i think):

1. Thread2 get the processor time and prints "run".
2. Thread2 gets interupted, and Thread1 takes over.
3. Thread1 prints "End of..."
4. Thread2 throws the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are possible. It's up to the thread scheduler to decide when instructions of concurrent threads are executed. The started thread and the main thread are run "in parallel", and the only guarantee is that the each thread's instructions are executed in sequence. But there could be any interleaving betwen the two sequences of operations.

You could also have the following, BTW.

```
run
end of method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem
```

To make an analogy, imagine you have a hurdle race, and you tell each runner to start the race, one at a time. Do you know which runner will come at each hurdle in first position? No, you don't. It depends on the speed of each runner. If the first runner to start is very slow, the last runner could come at the first hurdle before him. That's the same with threads. The scheduler assigns each running thread to a core, in any order he wants to, and for any time it decides. The only guarantee you have is that each thread will be executed some time.

Answer (score 2):

`t.start();` tells the system to start the thread - nothing says that the system has to actually give the thread execution time right away.

Another possibility is:

```
run.
End of method.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that the `Exception`'s stack trace is usually printed to the `stderr` stream of the process, while you write to the `stdout`. Often `stderr` is redirected to `stdout`, but this is not required.

Another thing to consider is that the documentation doesn't state anything about the concurrent access of `PrintStream#println()`, so the output when two threads try to print at the same time is truly umpredictable.

Given that it doesn't make much sense to have the exception stack trace in the game (because it's another stream altogether), the problem is reduced to which between the main thread and the other one writes first. Not only this is up to the JVM scheduler, but also consider that the method is not synchronized, so it could even print an interleaved string (well, I don't think this will ever happen in reality, but this is what *may* happen).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "why can the output of 'run' be printed after the exception is printed". They are in the same thread, and should execute in sequence, which should guarantee `System.out.print("run");` execute first then `throw new RuntimeException("Problem");`is executed after that.

The problem here is those two lines of code uses different printing queue. `System.out.print()` use the standard output, while the error message caused by `throw new RuntimeException("Problem");`will go to the standard error output. So which message prints first not only depends on which line of code gets executed first, but also which output queue flushed to screen first.

If the second line of code is `System.out.print("problem");` then 'problem' will always print after 'run' since they are using the same output queue